# javascript how to detect pressed key and replace with html

Tags: javascript, jquery

i've a text editor and i want to detect character inserted from keyboard and replace it with `<strong>pressed Key</strong>` 
i have tried this

```js
 $(div).keyup(function (event) {
     selection = saveSelection(div); //save the pointer position in div
 });

 function replace() {
     var key = true;
     restoreSelection(div, selection); //restore the pointer position in div

     $(div).focus().keydown(function (evt) {
         if (key) //prevent from repeat  
         {
             evt.preventDefault();
             evt = evt || window.event;
             var charCode = typeof evt.which == "number" ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
             var keyChar = String.fromCharCode(charCode); //this Does'nt work well
             replaceSelectionWithHtml('<strong>' + keyChar + '</strong>');
             key = false;
         }
     });
 }
```

and then `focus()` to `strong` that created to continue typing ! (How??)

i have tried this but not working in this case :

```js
 restoreSelection( div , selection );
 $(div).focus();
```

2nd question is when we are writing within `strong` or `em` how to `blur()` from it (closing this tag) and continue writing !?

**UPDATE :**

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/mt382861/3FZyq/3/) is a Demo .

Comment: If you make a JSfiddle... then people may be able to help you better...

Comment: Why would you want to re-invent this wheel?  There are lots of browser-based HTML editors already.  (ckeditor, tinymce, etc)

Comment: because i want to try and create it myself

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="inputText"><br><br>
<div id="displayText"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $('document').ready(function(){

        $('#inputText').keyup(function (evt) {
            var val = $(this).val();
            $('#displayText').html('<strong>' + val + '</strong>');
        });
    });

 </script>
```

Comment: no , i don't want this , this is very simple way and not useable for my issue .

Comment: Mohamad Talkhabi... Meaning i didn't understand your question... may be you re-phrase your question again